# playwright python how to get specific texts follwing sibling inner text value

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I am trying to get the next sibling and next siblings that are in row using the text that occurring in the DOM. but i can't get it by using text that are in DOM

> Here i have the selected row's text content, by using the text content i don't know how to get the `following-sibling`(in `td tag`) and that sibling's child(in `span and small tag`).

[image: DOM structure]

[image: sibling]

[image: sibling's childs]

so far i have tried this

```
    for number in range(len(pan_ids)):
    if (await page.locator(f"text={pan_ids[number]}").is_visible() ==True):
        print(f"pan number : {number}")
        if (await page.locator('td:right-of(:text("{pan_ids[number]}")').is_visible() ==True):
            pass
    else:
        await page.locator('[aria-label="Next page"]').click()
        print(f"pan number : {pan_ids[number]}")
```

but not getting the result i really don't know where i am lagging.
Any help would be appreciated mates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `below` ([Reference](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/1.23/selectors#selecting-elements-based-on-layout)).

```py
await page.locator('td > small:below(:text("{pan_ids[number]}")').text_content()
```

Or, You can also use the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

```py
await page.locator(':text("{pan_ids[number]}") + td > small').text_content()
```

Comment: I want to get the inner texts of siblings

Comment: You want the inner text of all `td` or just the the `td` next to the pan id?

Comment: only want next to pan id

Comment: You can add `text_content()`, it will extract the inner text. Updated the answer.

Comment: what about the span and small tags ?? how to get  them?